# Libgdx Recoil Effect

Tags: java, libgdx

I set -velocityX to my sprite gun.

```
float velocityX = -20 * dt;
if(trigger) {
   gun.setX(gun.getX() + velocityX);
}
```

I basically set a velocity of -20m/s to my gun vertex X. The problem is when I rotate the gun in a vertical position or example: 30degree angle.

[image]

How can I add recoil effect even if the sprite is not in a horizontal position, or should I just add it in the animation?

Comment: You want to move the recoil alone your gun's x-axis. Your function doesn't take this into account and just keeps moving it along the x-axis of the world coordinates. An idea would be to have a `recoil` function and in order to properly calculate the recoil you have to calculate the gun's x-axis in world coordinates and move it then accordingly.

Comment: Even if I do that, it will only move on x axis. How can I deal with the y axis?